# Can bool be easily converted to a Sign?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Currently i have the following code

```
if(BlackScreenAlpha > 1f){
    BlackScreenAlphaIncrease = false;
}
if(BlackScreenAlphaIncrease == true){
    BlackScreenAlpha += 0.01f;
}else{
    BlackScreenAlpha -= 0.01f;
}
```

Which Currently changes the alpha of an image from 0, to 1, back to 0 again. I have encountered this a few times in my project, and am now wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Is there a better way to correspond the BlackScreenAlphaIncrease bool more directly to how BlackScreenAlpha changes? I.e directly convert 'true' to the '+' sign, and likewise 'false' to the '-' sign?

(I do not believe a while loop is appropriate, as this is only a slither of my code and other stuff runs between each increment/decrement)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have a "sign", unless you do something like this:

```
float signMultiplier;
if(BlackScreenAlphaIncrease)
{
    signMultiplier = 1;
}
else
{
    signMultiplier = -1;
}

BlackScreenAlpha += (signMultiplier * 0.01f);
```

But this is less readable. What about using the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) instead?:

```
BlackScreenAlpha += BlackScreenAlphaIncrease ? 0.01f : -0.01f;
```

Comment: You could do version 1 as a ternary also. `if(... == true)` is just weird anyway